# JQuery slidedown effect not working?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a form which when submitted would be validate first and if the form is not valid, it gill get back to the form page again and show errors.

This is the div that contains the error:

```
<div id="error"><?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?></div>
```

I am using CodeIgniter by the way.

I wanted the form to slideDown when the user would be navigated back to the form page so I got a script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#error').slideDown('slow');
});
```

My problem is, I can't figure how how to slide down the form even if I already have the script above. It will just show normally without any animations. Did I missed something?

Please do help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure #error is hidden to begin with, otherwise there's nothing to slide down.

Answer (score 2):

`$(sel).slideDown()` will only work if the div is not already visible

Another answer suggests you use `style="display:none;"` however, this is obtrusive and error messages will not be seen by js-disabled browsers.

I'd use:

```
$(function(){
  $("#error").hide().slideDown();
});
```

[see it working here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpBRe/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

set div to hidden

```
<div id="error" style="display:none"><?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?></div>


$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#error').slideDown('slow');
    $('#error').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is obtrusive javascript and the error will not be displayed for js-disabled clients.

Comment: You found the solution? What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the script you have at the bottom of the page, for example before the closing `</body>` tag. It won't work if it's in your `<head>`.

Comment: he's using `$(document).ready(fn)` so your response is irrelevant.